# Vue.js 2/Vuex - Scrollbar just breaks for some reason

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

Got a strange issue that i've not been able to easily replicate whilst building an app on vue.js 2 and vuex.

I've got a table where i can add and remove rows. The rows coming from the Vuex state and i've been commiting and mutating the state in the usual way and it's working great.

However, sometimes the window scrollbar just breaks and stops working so can't scroll up/down (or has the app hung?!). If I refresh the page, everything works again.

I get no errors and Vue dev tools doesn't report anything weird.

I also get the same issue in other browsers, thinking it might have something to do with Vue Tools (just to rule it out).

Be great to get any ideas on what the problem could be - if its a conflict with another library/package, memory leaking causing it to freeze/hang etc. Thanks in advance.

These are my package.json dev/dependancies:

devDependencies:

- "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
- "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
- "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
- "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
- "gulp": "^3.9.1",
- "laravel-elixir": "^5.0.0",
- "laravel-mix": "^0.9.2",
- "nightwatch": "^0.9.13",
- "nightwatch-tools": "^0.1.0",
- "selenium-download": "^2.0.9",
- "selenium-webdriver": "2.44.*"

Dependencies:

- "animate-sass": "^0.6.6",
- "axios": "^0.15.3",
- "blueimp-md5": "^2.7.0",
- "bootstrap-select": "^1.12.2",
- "fecha": "^2.3.0",
- "jasny-bootstrap": "^3.1.3",
- "jquery": "^3.1.1",
- "lodash": "^4.17.4",
- "moment": "^2.18.1",
- "sweetalert2": "^6.4.2",
- "validator": "^7.0.0",
- "vee-validate": "^2.0.0-beta.25",
- "vue": "^2.2.3",
- "vue-default-value": "^1.0.2",
- "vue-loader": "^11.1.4",
- "vue-localstorage": "^0.1.3",
- "vue-multiselect": "^2.0.0-beta.15",
- "vue-scrollto": "^2.4.2",
- "vue-strap": "github:wffranco/vue-strap",
- "vue-template-compiler": "^2.2.3",
- "vue2-dragula": "^2.4.4",
- "vue2-filters": "^0.1.6",
- "vuex": "^2.1.2"

Answer (score 4):

I managed to figure out the issue. Was an issue with using vue-strap spinner within a modal window and a rogue 'overflow-y:hidden' wasn't being removed on completion of that task causing the 'disabled' scroll.

Comment: I had this issue with a modal from https://uiv.wxsm.space/ - I wasn't using the v-model binding correctly and an overflow-y style (via a css class) was applied to the document body.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for sharing the solution. I don't know yet exactly what the issue is with my application but it was strangely misbehaving, after loading data to an entity object coming from the DB or right after starting typing a new entity the page was scrolling all way to the top and "freezing". Although I still could interact using the keyboard. The would even scroll if I move the focus to a control down below.